# must implement the inherited method ApplicationListener.render()

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, libgdx

I keep getting this error:

"The type MainMenu must implement the inherited abstract method ApplicationListener.render()"

MY code:
    package com.gdx.game.Screens;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import aurelienribon.tweenengine.BaseTween;
import aurelienribon.tweenengine.Tween;
import aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenCallback;
import aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenEquations;
import aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenManager;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.gdx.game.Asteroid;
import com.gdx.game.TweenAccessors.SpriteTween;

public class MainMenu implements  ApplicationListener, Screen
{
//private Boolean isMain = false;                   //Boolean to check if the menu screen can exit
private Texture menuTexture;                    //Splash screen image
private Sprite  menuSprite;                 //Image manipulation
private SpriteBatch batch;                      //Container to bundle Sprites to speed up performance
private Asteroid game;              
private TweenManager manager;                   //Updates all tweens at once
private TweenCallback callBack;     

//SplashScreen constructor
public MainMenu(Asteroid game)
{
    this.game = game;
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) 
{

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);                   //Set color to black
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);       //Clear the color
    manager.update(delta);
    //Begin drawing
    batch.begin();

    if((Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.ENTER)))
    {
        batch.dispose();
        //game.setScreen(gameClass(game));
    }

    menuSprite.draw(batch);

    //End drawing
    batch.end();
}
```

I can still run my code but when I try and press enter It terminates and I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: buffer not allocated with newUnsafeByteBuffer or already disposed
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.BufferUtils.disposeUnsafeByteBuffer(BufferUtils.java:277)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.VertexArray.dispose(VertexArray.java:71)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Mesh.dispose(Mesh.java:415)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.dispose(SpriteBatch.java:1094)
at com.gdx.game.Screens.MainMenu.render(MainMenu.java:50)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at com.gdx.game.Asteroid.render(Asteroid.java:24)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:202)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:131)
AL lib: ReleaseALC: 1 device not closed
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the `render` method defined in ApplicationListener:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta)
```

The [real render method](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/ApplicationListener.html#render%28%29) has no arguments.

There should be a warning in your editor/compiler that the @Override annotation triggered.

Comment: He didn't get any warning because he also implemented Screen there :S which render method does have a float as argument.